# Trouble installing openSSL MacOs X gcc-9 for C/C++

Tags: c, macos, compilation, openssl

To summarize my problem: I started learning C++, downloaded latest gcc-9 compiler, and I wanted to learn a bit more about socket programming in C++, especially SSL sockets. 
So I naturally found the OpenSSL library which meets all I need, and I wanted to start using it, but this is where things are getting complicated ...

(Coming from Node.js, Python, and PHP package downloading was not really an issue.)

I found several websites like those followings:

- [OpenSSL official documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation)
- [and this one](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/)
- [and this one similar to the one above](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username)

which show how to install the library and to compile it.

As far As I understand the installation process, the lines:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.1a
```

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/macos-x86_64
```

```
./config --prefix=/home/username/openssl --openssldir=/home/username/openssl no-ssl2
```

are used to specify the installation location/directory of the resulting compilation. Then according to the websites, they change some settings in `.bash_profile` file in order to use the right version of openssl when using `openssl` as a command line tool.

That brings us to my main question, when creating a C++ file and writing the sources how can including those files work:

```c
#include <openssl/myname.h>
```

Because, depending on which tutorial I follow, the packages will be installed in different locations in the filesystem, and including a file using `<` and `>` makes the preprocessor search in specific locations? 
So how can I make those things the right way; this is really unclear in my mind?

And also is the directory where I do the compilation important or not? I saw in some tutorial that we were asked to move to a special location before downloading sources and starting compilation.

Comment: After you've installed the compiled software in its target location, you can destroy the build directories — indeed, you normally want to do that to save space.  You might well keep the downloaded source and any build instructions you create (documenting which install location you use, etc) so that you can recompile when necessary, but the actual extracted source should be deleted after installation and basic testing.

Comment: @CYRUS It was my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `make && make install`, you run:

```
g++ -I/path/to/directory/where/openssl/is/installed/include source-file.cc
```

to compile your program.